# Laravel 4 : How to Change Laravel getQueryLog to complete SQL command

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, query-builder

I can't express Question well in English

You know my English is poor.

That's not the point

---

When I use getQueryLog() to get the last executed query.

But I get the response

```
[query] => select * from table where`teacher_oid` = ? and `class_oid` = ? 
[bindings] => Array
    (
        [0] => 'tid'
        [1] => 'cid'
    )

[time] => 12.58
```

Is there a way automatically written bindings[0] to first "?" bindings[1] to second "?" ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. Unfortunately there is not. This is a limitation of PHP's PDO.

However you can still find the final query.

I accomplish this by [enabling MySQL's query logging](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html) in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` (The location of your mysql configuration file may be different).

You want to enable the `general_log` inside of `my.cnf` and then restart MySQL. Then in `/var/log/mysql.log`, you'll see each query made to the database.

Only do this in a development server, not in production.